# Xcode 3 and iOS 6

Tags: xcode

A newbie question. I have Xcode 3.2.6 and my ipad is iOS 6.0. It seems this version of Xcode doesn't support the iOS version. What version do I need to upgrade my Xcode to so that I can test apps on devices running iOS 6.

And, my second question do I have to download the .dmg to upgrade Xcode. Currently I am running snow leopard 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need OS X Lion 10.7.4 or later to install the latest version of [Xcode from the AppStore](https://itunes.apple.com/hr/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12). Then you will be able to build apps to your device with iOS 6.0.

Comment: I am in a country with very poor broadband access. If internet disconnects while downloading lion from App Store, does it continue from where it left off?

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 6 you will need Xcode 4.5 and at least Lion (10.7)